# Does Gatling support injecting users at milliseconds intervals

Tags: gatling

While learning and implementing for one of the projects, we were asked to see if there is a way to inject users at milliseconds interval, something like 10 users in 100 milliseconds? Is this possible in Gatling.

Thanks,
mpha

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something like this would do what you're looking for, where totalUsers is however many users you want to inject in total:

```
.inject(splitUsers(totalUsers) into atOnceUsers(10) separatedBy(100 milliseconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setUp(myScenario.inject(rampUsers(10).over(new FiniteDuration(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))))
```

if users are not ramped-up, you may need to increase no. of milliseconds